# How do i write a function to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

So i have this function in php which displays a set of form inputs

```
    function column_display(){
 static $i = 0;
  $i++;
echo'<td><input type="number" name="spent'.$i.'"></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" placeholder="Enter Bill no. and Bill date" name="bill'.$i.'"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" placeholder="Name of the vendor" name="vendor'.$i.'" maxlength="45"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" placeholder="Additional details of expenditure" name="detail'.$i.'" maxlength="45"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" placeholder="Enter Quantity" name="quantity'.$i.'" maxlength="25"></textarea></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" placeholder="Remark/Comment" name="remark'.$i.'" maxlength="45"></textarea></td>
          </tr>';

            }
```

The counter runs from 1 to 17. i.e 17 times and i have to post each input to update my table. Is there any shortcut that i can request them in a loop and also update them into a existing table.
This is how I am doing now

```
UPDATE school_release 

SET item_spent = CASE WHEN item_id = 'it1' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent1'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it2' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent2'               
                  WHEN item_id = 'it3' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent3'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it4' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent4'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it5' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent5'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it6' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent6'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it7' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent7'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it8' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent8'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it9' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent9'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it10' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent10'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it11' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent11'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it12' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent12'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it13' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent13'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it14' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent14'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it15' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent15'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it16' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent16'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it17' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent17'
                  ELSE item_spent
                 END,
SET item_bill =  CASE WHEN item_id = 'it1' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent1'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it2' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent2'               
                  WHEN item_id = 'it3' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent3'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it4' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent4'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it5' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent5'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it6' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent6'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it7' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent7'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it8' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent8'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it9' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent9'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it10' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent10'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it11' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent11'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it12' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent12'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it13' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent13'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it14' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent14'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it15' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent15'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it16' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent16'
                  WHEN item_id = 'it17' AND stamp = '$stamp' AND school_id = '$school_id' THEN '$spent17'
                  ELSE item_spent
                 END,
```

.
.
.
.
.
 SET item_remark =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting `$i` in each of the names, give them array-style names like `name="bill[]"` and `name="vendor[]"`. Then `$_POST['bill']` and `$_POST['vendor']` will be arrays, and you can loop through them:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO yourTable (bill, vendor, detail, quantity, remark) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");;
$stmt->bind_param("sssis", $bill, $vendor, $detail, $quantity, $remark);
foreach ($_POST['bill'] as $i => $bill) {  
    $vendor = $_POST['vendor'][$i];
    $detail = $_POST['detail'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $remark = $_POST['remark'][$i];
    $stmt->execute();
}
```